# Limiting property of polylogarithm ratio

Tags: real-analysis, limits-and-convergence, polylogarithms

I try (without success) to figure out what could be the following limit if any...
For real $s$ strictly $> 1$ and $x \rightarrow +\infty$ (x real) the limit of the polylogarithm ratio $\frac{Li_{s-1}(x)}{Li_{s}(x)}$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: this follows from the asymptotic expansion given in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Asymptotic_expansions

Comment: Thanks a lot Carlo. That helps me.